# Spring security oAuth2.0 authenticate with Twitter

Tags: java, spring-boot, twitter, spring-security, social-networking

I have a question how to do the same authorization for twitter, as you know twitter is on oAuth1.0a and requires some request token, what I tried is this in my *yaml property file:

```
twitter:
clientId: my_twitter_client_id_goes_here
clientSecret: my_twiiter_client_secret_goes_here
redirectUriTemplate: "{baseUrl}/oauth2/callback/{registrationId}"
authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
scope:
- email
- profile
provider:
twitter:
authorizationUri: api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
tokenUri: api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
userInfoUri: api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json
```

but I always get the same page from twitter: 
**Whoa there!**
**There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.**

any help would be appreciated 
p.s. google and facebook are working fine because they are on oAuth2.0